# Get style/font (font size, color etc) of current paragraph via Word API

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am working on a word web add-in that involves inserting some text (as OOXML) into a word document.

The insert functionality is working fine but I want the inserted text to have the same font size and colour etc as the area the user is currently editing.

I have got this working to some degree by getting the current paragraph at the cursor like so:

```
Word.run((context) => {
    var pars = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
    pars.load();

    return context.sync().then(() => {
            var par = pars.items[0];
            var font = par.font.load();
            var style = par.style;

            // Do stuff with the style & font...
    });
});
```

However this seems to be unreliable and sometimes doesn't work.

I want to get the style at the current typing location, or somehow read them directly from the values in the ribbon:

[image]

Is there a good way to do this? It seems like this would be a pretty common use case in a word add-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`paragraph`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph) isn't going to be reliable scope since it could easily contain content using multiple fonts and sizes. You're also retrieving only the 1st paragraph which even *more* likely to have a different properties (i.e. a title).

To grab the font information for the exact spot you want to insert your `OOXML`, you want to use [`document.getSelection()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document#getselection) to return a [`range`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) object. This will let you fetch the current font at the cursor's location:

```js
return Word.run(function (context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    range.load('font');

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Font: " + range.font.name);
            console.log("Size: " + range.font.size);
        });
});
```

Note that if the user has a selection that contains multiple fonts, this will return a `null` for `font`. To get around that you can rescope the `range` to the start of the section using [`getRange("start")`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range#getrangerangelocation-string):

```js
return Word.run(function (context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    range = range.getRange("start");
    range.load('font');

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Font: " + range.font.name);
            console.log("Size: " + range.font.size);
        });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work just how I wanted, thanks. I knew I would be missing something simple.

Comment: yes, load('font') and a context sync is what is needed to be able to properly get font properties like font size